# computer algorithm to calculate shear center

Tags: structural-engineering

Without using FEA, is there a computer algorithm or numerical method available to calculate the shear center of any 2D geometry if the following are known:

geometry of the individual components of the section mesh;  centroid;
   principal axes angle of rotation;
 area;
 perimeter;
 moments of inertia
   x and y;
 radius of gyration;

Thanks

Comment: Sure. Though a sweep line algorithm is exactly the same alogrithm as the FEA algorithm (without meshing) and its easiest to implement. So any competent programmer would probably use that instead especially since they would trivially get all the other things calculated at the same time.